# IOS7 Restrict MapView to a certain area or region

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Does anybody know how to restrict the mapview to a certain region but still allow zoom and scroll within the region but lock the map so it would not go outside the region. I have tried using UIScrollViewDelegate but it doesnt work for IOS6 and up. I also tried using regiondidchanged but that doesnt lock the scroll and panning outside of the region.

thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

I've done that before in the regiondidchanged method.
In fact if the center of your map comes outside your defined region (test latitude and longitude), just reset the map to the center of the region...

```
if(![self isValid:self.mapView.center])
    [self.mapView setRegion:defaultValidRegion animated:YES];
```

**EDIT**

Have you tried to consider this project : [GeoFencer](https://github.com/jamgraham/geoFencer) ? It seems that it correspond except that there is a problem in his algorithm when it search for mapView'scrollview, but it can be solved I think by replacing

```
UIScrollView * scroll = [[[[mapView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

by

```
UIScrollView * scroll = [[[[mapView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Try to use in the debugger with this command to locate the correct scrollview in the view hierarchy

```
po [self.mapView recursiveDescription]
```

Comment: that didnt work. calling regionDidChangeAnimated is too late. The mapview has changed by the time that event is called. I need to prevent the region from being moved without the user seeing the mapview moved maybe via scrolling or something.